# Apply different styles when routerlink active and not active

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Im trying to have a Menu in Angular, that holds four Menu Items.
All of these should be underlined with one gapless line.
The active Menu item should be underlined in another color.

The struggle is, the route is set dynamically so i cant apply conditions based on a fixed route.

My Take was this:

(This is a component that is loaded 4 times in a parent component, packed in a ul)

```
<div  routerLinkActive="border-b-4  border-primary font-semibold text-primary"
 class=" border-grey border-b-4 px-4  ">

  <a
    class="  px-2 pb-4 text-gray"
    routerLink="{{routeTo}}"
  >{{ tabName }}</a
  >
```

It does what i want when the site loads, but as soon as i click at one of the menu items and then at another, the grey underlining of that item is permanently removed.
So when all Menu items are clicked, none is underlined grey anymore.

I tried to set the grey border bottom to the ul in the previous component, but then the highlighted bottom is just stacked upon the grey one, as its not the same height.
Another Idea was to use ngClass but i cant get it to work.

Comment: Could you replicate this on stackblitz?

Comment: With an example it could be easier, but at first sight, why don't you inject some data when you generate your components ? Some kind of ID you could rely on for the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.
Answer is

```
<li  #rla="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive [ngClass]="{'border-primary':rla.isActive}" 
 class=" px-4  border-b-4">

  <a
    class=" text-gray"
    routerLink="{{routeTo}}"
  >{{ tabName }}</a
  >
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the first answer does not explain what the cause is. Hence I'm adding another answer to elaborate.

**Cause**

What happens is that the `routerLinkActive` directive applies all the classes you've assigned to it.
Then when a route is no longer active, it will remove all of the classes it applied **from the class-attribute**.

I.e. if there is an intersection between the classes already present in the `class`-attribute or `ngClass` directive then only the distinct classes are applied.

The [directive's documentation](https://v16.angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description) explicitly states:
"If the URL changes, the class is removed.".
It seems however that it does not factor in already applied classes. This is a reasonable approach since you don't want to reapply a class which should be active in both active and inactive links.

Note: The link above references documentation for v16, but I've tested this for v16 and v15. The issue is present in both versions and the solution is the same.

**Solution**

Make sure that the classes in the `class`-attribute or `ngClass` directive are distinct from the classes in `routerLinkActive` by removing the classes from `routerLinkActive`.

**Example**

Given:

A template

```
  <a *ngFor="let route of routes"
     [routerLink]="route.path"
     [ngClass]="['class-1']"
     [routerLinkActive]="['class-1', 'class-2']"
     [ariaCurrentWhenActive] ="page">
    {{ route.title }}
  </a>
```

A Router config

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "x",
    component: XComponent,
    title: "Typography"
  },
  {
    path: "y",
    component: YComponent,
    title: "Y"
  }]
```

When:

- Navigating to `/x`.

Then:

- 'class-1' and 'class-2' are applied to the active route for `/x`.

When:

- Navigating to `/y`

Then:

- No classes are applied to the active route for `/x`.

Reason:

This is due to the removal of 'class-1' which is both in `ngClass` and `routerLinkActive`.

Solution:

```
  <a *ngFor="let route of routes"
     [routerLink]="route.path"
     [ngClass]="['class-1']"
     [routerLinkActive]="['class-2']"
     [ariaCurrentWhenActive] ="page">
    {{ route.title }}
  </a>
```